# ActiveAdmin ACL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acl, activeadmin

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and one of the things that I like is the admin generator bundles like RailsAdmin ActiveAdmin etc.
In my next project I'd like to use Ruby on Rails 3 and ActiveAdmin as backend. But I have no idea of how to achieve ACL in ActiveAdmin.
Can someone explain or point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

Active Admin uses the Devise gem for authentication. The Devise team have a wiki on how to use cancan for authorization here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Integrate-with-CanCan-for-roles-management

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin has rather poor support for authorization in my opinion.  If you want integrated CanCan then I recommend going with RailsAdmin.  It unfortunately is not as customizable as ActivAdmin though.

Comment: my thoughts exactly, active admin is easier to play with and customize to your needs.